# Logger Showing Wrong Date

Tags: date, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've implemented a script to group individual sheets into spreadsheets based on month and year. Everything is working on 2 of the 3 sheets except for the last one that I have implemented.

The code is basically copied and pasted into each of the spreadsheets. The issue I'm getting is with the date on one of them: it is consistently 1 day behind.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var dateRange = ss.getRange(2,7).getValue(); // Value in Cell G2 is "7/17/2018"
Logger.log(dateRange); // Returns Mon Jul 16 20:00:00 GMT-04:00 2018
Logger.log(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(dateRange), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "yyyy-MM-dd"));// returns 2018-07-16
```

This is in contrast to the other script where it is working correctly:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var dateRange = ss.getRange(1,2).getValue(); // Value in Cell B1 is "7/17/2018"
Logger.log(dateRange); // Returns Tue Jul 17 00:00:00 GMT-04:00 2018
Logger.log(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(dateRange), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "yyyy-MM-dd")); // Returns 2018-07-17
```

Any insight as to why nearly identical code is returning 2 different values? The cells themselves are formatted in google sheets as dates and have data validation so that they are input correctly as a valid date.

Edit:

To clarify my goal, what I am trying to do, is ensure both return 7/17/2018 so that when I group sheets by date, the appropriate date is reflected. Currently the sheet with the top code will be grouped into 7/16 despite the fact that the cell will show 7/17 on the sheet.

Thank you!

Comment: In the spreadsheet, if you go to File > Spreadsheet settings, does the time zone there match that of your script?

Comment: @Diego Yes they do.

Comment: @tehhowch How would I go about doing that? I just want to input a date like 7/17 and get it to be 7/17

Comment: @jsims2 in JavaScript, `Date`s always include time information - they represent a given number of milliseconds since the UTC epoch. You cannot avoid timezones when working with `Date` objects. You don't share your goal here - are you comparing dates? If so, that will work just fine. Just don't forget to use `Date#getTime()` if you are using `==` as your comparison operator.

Comment: @tehhowch
My goal is that the same code in two different sheets is showing 2 different dates. I'm trying to figure out why they are and how to avoid it. When it indexes it by month, it saves the file as the 7/16 in the top script

Comment: They're the same `Date`, though. What happens if you use the Spreadsheet time zone for formatting instead of the script tz? https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSpreadsheetTimeZone()

Comment: @tehhowch tested it and this worked. But the original code works as well. Any ideas as to why this suddenly works? Could you also explain the benefit to using spreadsheet time zone vs script even though the properties show the same timezone for both?